# Java SimpleDateFormat question marks instead of Month

Tags: java, jsp, datetime

I want to display the current month, date, year and time.
I have a .jsp file which has the following code inside:

```
 <%
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh:mm");
   String date = format.format(new Date());
 %>

<%=date%>
```

The output on the page is:

```
??? 13,2016 04:14
```

So, the month isn't displayed.
But when I use `M` instead of `MMM`it works:

```
10 13,2016 04:17
```

But I need a full name of the month, and neither `MMM` nor `MMMM` works. The `MMMM` gives the similar output:

```
??????? 13,2016 04:18
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: works fine for me in Java.  What locale are you in?

Comment: Try *SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh:mm",Locale.US)*.

Comment: @blackpen It worked! How come it couldn't display it without use of `Locale`?

Comment: I assume you are on linux. Try "locale" command. Check in your ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile. You are probably using a foriegn language locale. Do you need to display date in any foriegn language? If not you can set your locale in your shell environment. I think that will solve your issue.

Comment: @blackpen I'm on Windows, but still thanks, I'll look into the topic. You can copy your answer so I could accept it, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try *`SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm",Locale.US)`*.

If you are trying to print date in a foriegn locale (or if your locale seems to be wrong), you can change it in your environment so that it can generate the name of the month correctly.

You can set your system locale in Windows using control panel like ***`Start->Control Panel->Clock,Language and Region`*** like shown [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml). You can also change locale per user as discussed in this detailed [FAQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688174.aspx)

If you are on linux, you can set your locale in system configuration OR in your HOME directory as discussed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale)